# Multiple MySQL database in single connection

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, connection

I have a problem on using 2 database in a single script , this is how my code look likes, and i want to show two data from2 different database, is there something wrong with this,or is this possible with this type? hoping for your kind help, thanks

```
        <?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "2125";
    $database = "db_hris";

    $hostt = "1.1.1.1";
    $usert = "test";
    $passwordt = "2125";
    $databaset = "db_hris";

    mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_connect($hostt, $usert, $passwordt, true) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($database) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($databaset) or die (mysql_error());


    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_log WHERE stafflog_id!=3 ORDER BY stafflog_id DESC LIMIT 1 ,$databaset");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $un = $row['staff_un'];
    $stat = $row['log_status'];

    }

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_staff , $database");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $id=$row['stafflog_id'];
    }
    echo $un;
    echo $id;
    ?>
```

I cant echo out the $un and the $id, im planning on getting the staff_un from another database and compare it to the staff_id of a different database so that i can do whatever i want after that, i basically need to catch the id from another database.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one connection to your code. Just use the primary database that you need. then if you want to combine the data of two databases. Use View, Stored Proc or Function. It is more easy to manipulate data with this 3.